# What steps can I take to prevent a seizure from occurring?

Tags: seizure, prevention

> An epileptic seizure is a transient occurrence of signs and/or
>   symptoms due to abnormally excessive or synchronous neuronal activity
>   in the brain. - [Wiley Online Library](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0013-9580.2005.66104.x/abstract)

What can I do to prevent myself from getting a epileptic seizure? Cause-effect answers that explain triggers would be appreciated.

Comment: This is effectively three questions in one.  First it is asking what is a seizure, and second it is asking how to prevent getting one, and third it is asking how are they triggered.

Comment: Does this assume that you have some preexisting condition, or not?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. Since the question offers no narrowing of scope it boils down to: What causes epilepsy? Far too broad a question to be answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found following peer-reviewed paper which provides a review of the nonpharmaceutic conservative interventions for the prevention of seizures:

*Wolf P. The role of nonpharmaceutic conservative interventions in the treatment and secondary prevention of epilepsy. Epilepsia. 2002;43 Suppl 9:2-5.* [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12383271)

It says (I have kept the essential parts):

> **The first step is the identification of factors facilitating the
>   occurrence of seizures. In the second step, strategies to control
>   these factors are developed.** Most common are disturbances of the
>   sleep-wake cycle, especially reduction of sleep. **Patients should
>   follow a regular sleep schedule with deviations of not >2 h.** Sometimes
>   a sleep calendar is helpful. Night shifts are not compatible with
>   seizure prevention in these cases. (...) O**ther nonspecific
>   facilitators of seizures include uncontrolled use of alcohol and
>   extraordinary stress. Patients must learn how to cope with stressful
>   events.**

It also provides some preventive measures for specific types of epilepsies:

> In **reflex epilepsies**, specific precipitants of seizures are the
>   targets of interventions. Thus, most patients with primary reading
>   epilepsy begin to have, with prolonged reading, perioral reflex
>   myoclonias, which enable them to stop reading and thus to avoid a GTC
>   seizure. In **photosensitive patients**, seizures are often precipitated
>   by television. These can be avoided by viewing from a distance and
>   using a remote control, small screens in a well-lit room, and
>   preferably with a 100-Hz line shift. Environmental flicker stimulation
>   often comes unexpectedly, and it is advisable that the patients always
>   wear sunglasses in brightly lighted surroundings. Polarized glasses
>   seem to be more protective than plain sunglasses. **If the patient has
>   only photically induced seizures**, treatment by specific prevention
>   alone may be sufficient, but if spontaneous seizures also occur, drugs
>   must be given in addition.

Hope this helps!